# Firebase Database Keeping The form inputs Field filled out

Tags: javascript, forms, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

My Situation: Currently, I have a form that pushes the user's information onto the firebase database.

The Problem Is: Every time the page reloads (even on navigation changed between, home.html and contacts.html) it will clear the user's inputs field.

My Question Is: Am I able to prevent the inputs Field from being cleared.

Potential Solution: I believe that I should be able to pull the information which was stored onto the database back onto the input fields. But as I'm fairly new to the backend I can't figure out the code for doing so.

The code which I have used to store the data is:

```js
// Savng Profile Info To Database
const profileForm = document.querySelector('.profile-form');
const submitBtn = document.querySelector('.submit');

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

 const fullName = profileForm['icon_prefix'].value;
 const bio = profileForm['icon_prefix11'].value;
 const email = profileForm['icon_prefix1'].value;
 const phone = profileForm['icon_prefix2'].value;
 const gender = profileForm['icon_prefix3'].value;

 db.collection('profile').doc().set({
    name: fullName,
    bio: bio,
    email: email,
    tel: phone,
    gender: gender
 }).then(() => {
  console.log('data saved');
 }).catch(() => {
     console.log(error);
 });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   
  <title>Document</title>

  <!-- Google icons -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Style.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">

  <!-- Materialize Style.css -->
  
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Manifest -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

  <!-- IOS Support -->

  <!-- Theme-Color For LightHouse Pwa -->
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#FFE1C4">
</head>
<body>


<main>

<!-- Form -->
  <div class="row profile_padding">
    <form class="col s12 profile-form" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
          <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate full-name"/>
          <label for="icon_prefix">Full Name </label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">chat</i>
          <textarea id="icon_prefix11" type="text" class="materialize-textarea validate"></textarea>
          <label for="icon_prefix11">Bio</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">mail</i>
          <input id="icon_prefix1" type="text" class="validate"/>
          <label for="icon_prefix1">Email Address</label>
        </div>
         <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
          <input id="icon_prefix2" type="tel" class="validate"/>
          <label for="icon_prefix2">Phone Number</label>
         </div>
         <div class="input-field col s12 profile_padding_bottom">
           <i class="material-icons prefix">perm_identity</i>
           <input id="icon_prefix3" type="text" class="validate"/>
           <label for="icon_prefix3">Gender</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col s12 center">
         <button class="submit btn-large black darken-4 z-depth-2 center" style="width: 100%; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 500; margin: 1rem 0 1rem 0;" >submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</main>  
           
 

    
<!-- Materialize.js -->
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
            
       
<!-- app.JavaScript -->
 <script src="/js/index.js"></script>

<!-- db.JavaScript -->
<script src="/js/db.js"></script>

<!-- auth.JavaScript -->
<script src="/js/auth.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're going to have to write a lot of code to periodically persist the values of each field somewhere, and use that to re-populate the form in the event of a reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the form info in a variable in memory/cache in order to keep the data and populate the form with it in case a refresh happens.

Querying Firestore every time there is a refresh would not be optimal, but you can always do so for example just for the first time you load the data

Answer (score 1):

You could remove all the content inside the form outside of the form. In another words, don't use form to submit data into Firebase. In that case, the user inputs won't be cleared unless you instruct to do so, and the page won't be reloaded unless you do so.

Comment: @bossmanhoy, did it work? If it did, make sure to upvote / select my answer. Thanks. If it did not work, let me know what the problem is, and I can provide you another solution